# JDeveloper 12c cannot run startWebLogic.cmd

Tags: java, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

Please note - this is my first Stack Overflow post, do not hesitate to notify me about any errors

---

---

**Problem:**

My JDeveloper 12c cannot run the startWebLogic.cmd file and subsequently cannot start the integrated WebLogic server.

The error message goes as follows:

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\App\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd 
The target IntegratedWebLogicServer cannot be started because an exception was thrown: java.io.IOException: 
Cannot run program "CC:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\App\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd" 
(in directory "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\App\JDeveloper\o.j2ee.adrs\instances\IntegratedWebLogicServer\DefaultWorkspace"): 
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

None of my colleagues has had this issue, the file is existing, I have tried to start JDeveloper with administrative privileges - to no success.
I also gave any local user on the system execution privileges for any file in this directory.

My operating system is Windows 7 Service Pack 1.

My JDK is jdk1.8.0_121

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
JDEV_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\App\JDeveloper
JDEV_USER_DIR=C:\Users\<username>\Documents
```

**EDIT**

1) I am able to run a standalone web server and deploy to that. Yet, I still cannot start the integrated web logic.

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the directory:
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\App\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\DefaultDomain
on your machine and restart JDeveloper - when you'll run your application JDeveloper will re-create the embedded WebLogic in that directory.

Comment: Unfortunately this did result in the same error as before. I suppose at this point, that this does not have anything to do with the jdeveloper but with something in my operating system.